# determine font size and weight of WKInterfaceLabel - needed for monospaced font

Tags: swift, watchkit

WatchKit supports [using a monospaced font for digits](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifont/1619022-monospaceddigitsystemfont).
Using Xcode 8.3.2 and WatchOS 3.

I believe I can not define/select this in the Interface Builder, therefore I need to set this manually. For this I can use:

```
class func monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize fontSize: CGFloat, 
                              weight: CGFloat) -> UIFont
```

It requires me setting the size and weight. I would like to inherit these from the label settings as defined in the Interface Builder.

But: how can I get the current size and weight of the label? It seems there's no method to get the current attributes. As a result it seems I need to hardcode it when applying the monospaced font.

```
@IBOutlet var myLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

extension WKInterfaceLabel {
  func setTextMono(_ str: String, size: CGFloat? = 15.0, weight: CGFloat? = UIFontWeightRegular) {
    let monospacedFont = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: size!, weight: weight!)
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: str, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : monospacedFont])
    self.setAttributedText(attributedString)
  }
}

myLabel.setTextMono("12:13.14", size: 32.0, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
```

Question: there is definitely not a way to get the current size and weight of the label and/or avoid having to provide these?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no method which returns font name, size. Also, you can't fetch the current text of the label too. Hope future versions of the watch allows more APIs to do stuff as there seems to be a lot of limitations in available versions.

For such kind of requirement, I did create constants and managed the font size and name. You can create constants, enums, structs, plist whatever is your preference.